# Range bounds of type Integral and/or RealFrac causing problems in nested list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, range, list-comprehension, ghc, integral

I'm trying to understand why for otherwise simple expressions, range bounds specified in Integral types cause ghc to reject a nested comprehension, when changing the range bounds to Num allows the same comprehension to execute successfully. For the cases below, ghc fails to compile a program invoking any of the *fails* functions, although the *works* all succeed.  In ghci, the code is accepted, but invoking any of the *fails* functions generates a runtime error ("No instance for (Show (Double -> [(a20, Integer)])) arising from a use of ‘print’").

Note that these are stripped-down test cases to explore the boundary of what ghc will or will not accept in a comprehension; I'm not looking for alternate code to iterate over these specific and fairly trivial ranges.  I also understand that in these particular cases, taking the *floor* of the upper bound doesn't really change the range being iterated over; however, it can be useful to force the iteration variables to have Integral type in subsequent filter expressions (not shown in these test cases).

```
fails0 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..floor x], z <- [2..floor y]]  -- second iteration expression depends on first, both are Integral
works0 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..floor x], z <- [2..floor x]]  -- second iteration expression independent of first
works1 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..x],       z <- [2..floor y]]  -- remove first floor (1st list is Num, 2nd still Integral)
works2 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..floor x], z <- [2..y]]        -- remove second floor (both lists Integral)
fails1 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..floor 5], z <- [2..floor y]]  -- first iteration range is constant and Integral
works3 x = [(y, z) | y <- [1..5],       z <- [2..floor y]]  -- first iteration range is constant but Num
```

As you can see, defining the first range with Num bounds, or removing the call to *floor* in the second sequence's bounces, or removing the dependence of the second range's bounds on the iterated value of the first (yet leaving both of Integral type), is enough to make it work. Without any of those changes, ghc reports an error of the form

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘fails0’ prevents the constraint ‘(RealFrac a0)’ from being solved. Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be. These potential instances exist:
        instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

Interestingly, the signatures of fails0 and works0 are nearly equivalent:

```
*Main> :t fails0
fails0
  :: (RealFrac a1, RealFrac a2, Integral a2, Integral b) =>
     a1 -> [(a2, b)]
*Main> :t works0
works0
  :: (RealFrac a1, Integral a2, Integral b) => a1 -> [(a2, b)]
```

(Tested on ghc 8.4.4 and 8.10.4.)

Is this intended behavior per the language design, or an implementation limitation?  Are there any best practices to ensure that more complex comprehensions, with dependencies between nested iteration ranges, will successfully compile?

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate problems here: (1) ambiguous types, (2) a confusion between integer and fractional numbers, and (3) trying to print the unprintable.

---

#### Let's start with the ambiguity

Consider the following program:

```
f x = []
```

And then consider the following definition:

```
x = f 42
```

**Question**: what is the type of `x`? Well, it's a generic type `[a]` of course. But say we wanted to know the concrete type, for example we might want to, hypothetically, print it out by calling `show x`. So which instance of `Show` would the compiler use for it? `Show [Int]`? Or `Show [String]`? Or perhaps `Show [Bool]`?

The answer is: neither. There is simply no context that the compiler could use to determine the type of `x` to lookup the appropriate instance of `Show`.

This is what is called "ambiguous type variable". The result of `f` could be of any type, and there is no way to determine which. Ambiguous.

And the only way to resolve this is to add a type annotation:

```
x :: [Int]
x = f 42
```

And so it is in your case: `fails0` returns a list of generic type, and there is no context from which to determine it.

**Hold on a second!** But then, how does `works0` work?

The [defaulting rules](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) of course! :-)

In Haskell numbers are generic. Perhaps a bit *too generic*. So that when you write `5`, it could mean `Integer`, or `Int`, or `Double`, or `Float`, and so on. And the only way to determine that is to add a type annotation. But of course, if we had to add a type annotation to every single number, that would be ridiculous, so GHC has special magic for this: without going into too much detail, whenever GHC sees a numeric-ish type, it tries to substitute a "reasonable" default, such as `Int` or `Double`.

And that's how `works0` works. GHC determines its type by defaulting, so you don't have to add a type signature.

But for `fails0` GHC doesn't use type defaulting, because it can't. Which brings us to...

---

#### Integer/fractional confusion

In the `fails0` equation, what type do you think `y` should be? There are two bits of evidence for that:

- `y` comes from a list from `1` to `floor x`, so it has to have the same type as `floor x`, which is any type that has an instance of `Integral` (according to [the type of `floor`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.18/base-4.14.3.0/Prelude.html#v:floor))
- `y` is used as an argument of `floor`, so it must be of a type that has an instance of `RealFrac` (also according to the type of `floor`)

So this means that:

```
y :: (RealFrac a, Integral a) => a
```

`y` should be of a type that has **both instances `ReactFrac` and `Integral`**

And this is what GHCi is telling you when you ask it for type of `fails0`. In your example, it denotes the type of `y` as `a2`, and indeed, `a2` has both `RealFrac` and `Integral` constraints.

GHCi is ok with it for now. It figured out the constraints, now it's waiting for you to call that function, and when you do, it dares you to choose a type `a2` such that it has both constraints.

But you can't! If you look at the [standard instances of `RealFrac`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.18/base-4.14.3.0/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac), and then [standard instances of `Integral`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.18/base-4.14.3.0/Prelude.html#t:Integral), you'll see that there is no type that has both of them. And this makes perfect sense: the `Integral` class is supposed to describe integer-ish numbers, while the `RealFrac` class is supposed to describe fractions. Any given type can't be both!

But the compiler is still fine with it. It's content to accept such function type, because by itself it doesn't really contradict anything. It's only when you try to *call it* that you discover that there is no possible type you could choose for `y`. Or, rather, the GHC discovers that when it tries to use the defaulting rules.

---

#### And finally, printing in GHCi

The way GHCi works, it waits for you to type in some Haskell code, and once you do, it compiles that code, executes it, and prints the result. And in order to print the result, the result has to have a `Show` instance.

According to your description:

> invoking any of the fails functions generates a runtime error ("No instance for (Show (Double -> [(a20, Integer)])) arising from a use of ‘print’").

See how GHCi is trying to find an instance `Show (Double -> [(a20, Integer)])`? It's trying to find a `Show` instance for *a function* (which don't exist, because functions are inherently non-printable)

And this means that the result of whatever you just typed is *a function*. I'm going to guess that you just typed `fails0` and forgot to give it an argument. So GHCi is trying to print `fails0` itself, not its return value.

If you do give it an argument, you will get a similar "ambiguous type" error.

Comment: Your first example seems like a bad example of ambiguity. The only thing that could be construed as ambiguous there is the input to `f`, but you only talked about the output being ambiguous.

Comment: My question isn't /what/ is failing at runtime, but /why/ GHC gives up. At the point of instantiation, all of the functions know the type of x. As long as it's something in the domain of floor, it should be possible to generate meaningful code. Furthermore, GHC knows from the type signature that floor's return value will be an Integral type, so the nested ranges are also Integral. fails0 actually has /more/ information about the z range bounds than works0 does. It looks like two independent variables is just a bit more complexity than the solver can handle; the defaulting rules are irrelevant.

Comment: Also, your first example is flawed.

`Prelude> f x = []`
`Prelude> g x = [x]`
`Prelude> f 42`
`[]`
`Prelude> g 42`
`[42]`

The type deduction is trivial, and well within GHC's capabilities.

Comment: I explained in much detail exactly why GHC refuses your program. Please reread carefully. Also, the error you get is not a runtime error, just FYI. As for my example, it wasn't meant to fail in GHCi, it was meant to have you answer the question: what is the type of `x`? Can you answer it?

Comment: Again, you're conflating abstract definitions and concrete instantiations. x in your program is effectively an alias for [] and has the same ungrounded dependent type signature [a]. The fact that it's ungrounded doesn't matter and doesn't prevent the compiler from generating deterministic, correct, and meaningful code (otherwise, [] and lists in general would be hard to use).  You can check [] == f 42, [3] == f 42, ["this", "is", "templating"] == 42, etc. and always get a sensible result.

Comment: I appreciate that you spent a lot of time trying to summarize what you understand of basic Haskell typing, but it doesn't answer my question, which was "why can the compiler figure out enough about the ranges
`y <- [1..floor x], z <- [2..floor x]]` or `y <- [1..x], z <- [2..floor y]]` to generate a comprehension, but it can't do the same with `y <- [1..floor x], z <- [2..floor y]]`?

Any arguments about type groundedness in fails0 would apply equally to works0 and/or works1, so that can't be the reason.

Comment: `fails0` fails because there is no type which is both `Integral` and `RealFrac`.